# QueryDSL Hibernate: order by intersection

Tags: hibernate, querydsl

I've got an entity Coder having 0-n Liking.
My query consists, given one named coder A, in finding all coders having at least one liking in common, ordered by descending count of common likings with A. Here is what it looks like so far:

```
query.from(coder, other)
     .where(
          coder.firstName.toLowerCase().eq(firstName)
          .and(coder.lastName.toLowerCase().eq(lastName))
          .and(other.ne(coder))
          .and(other.likings.any().in(coder.likings))
     )
     .orderBy(coder.likings.???);
```

Is there a way to achieve specifying a custon orderby with QueryDSL? I did not find anything relevant in `ListPath`. If so, I could use Guava to compute the intersection.

Thanks in advance,

Rolf

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try

```
    .orderBy(coder.likings.size().desc());
```

If that doesn't work try explicit aggregation with extra joins and group by.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. 
What I would actually like to do something like:
.orderBy(intersection(coder.likings, other.likings).size())

Comment: I think you can express that via joins and a groupBy.